# Cite-Tag for blockquotes

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, html

I want to have a cite underneath my blockquote, that has a certain style.

```
"Blockquotes are an essential part of a fancy website."
                                                – Cite
```

The markup should look like this:

```
<blockquote><p>Blockquotes are an essential part of a fancy website."</p>
<cite>Cite</cite></blockquote>
```

But the WYSIWYG-Editor does not offer me the possibility to define a cite for the blockquote. And I can't force my users to write the HTML by hand.

Is there a way to make the WYSIWYG-Editor generate the required markup?

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540789/correct-blockquote-markup-and-css-style or somehow essentially different?

Comment: It is completely different. Just the example is the same. I think this is easy to notice, even if my english isn't the best.

Comment: It actually isn't clear that that is a different question, nor is it entirely clear what you want with this question. Are you asking how to make the WYSIWYG editor generate all of that markup?

Comment: No, but the cite.

Comment: I think he's just trying to get the WYSIWYG editor to add in the Cite markup.

Comment: -1 for "*Preferably not another plugin...*" A Plugin is the proper way to extend functionality to implement a solution for this issue.

Comment: That is why I said "preferably" not "I want definitely no plugin, I hate plugins". What I meant is just: If there is a simple sollution, like adding two lines of code to functions.php, I would prefer that. (Instead of adding the Mega-Editor-Markup-Plugin-Pack for WP.)

Comment: And yes. I want the editor to add the cite markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [TinyMCE Custom Styles Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles) should get you through this.

There are code snippets on that page, but, as an overview, the process requires two steps:

1. Add the TinyMCE "styleselect" element to the first or second row of icons.
2. Add one or more elements to that styleselect menu.

If this were me, I would consider also *removing* the blockquote button from TinyMCE and then adding `blockquote` as an option in the styleselect along with `cite`. Doing it that way means your editors can find the correct markup for an entire `blockquote` in one place.

And I hope this goes without saying, but make sure to implement a [custom `editor-style.css` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style) so that the `blockquote` and `cite` styles match the theme output.